# PySpark import error in PyCharm, modules not installed, "no module named "error

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, pycharm

#### The Problem

When I want to import pyspark in a python script in PyCharm I get below error (cannot import x from y). I checked the directory and the module that should be imported is not present.

Thats all there is in `pyspark\cloudpickle\`
[image]

Why is it not installed? What could be possible problems?

#### What I tried

Compatibility issues? I found [this](https://gankrin.org/how-to-fix-importerror-no-module-named-error-in-spark/) which looks similar, but my error says "cannot import `name`"

I also found [this about cloudpickle](https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/26194#issuecomment-791632324) specifically, I tried with cloudpickle=1.1.1 but it didn't work for me.

I also made a new env, re-installed pyspark and rebooted, but it didn't help.

```
import findspark
findspark.init()
```

Works without error.

Obviously I'm new to Spark/PySpark and might miss the obvious...

#### Error

```
import pyspark

    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\me\anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3397, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-9-d008122bb79d>", line 3, in <cell line: 3>
    from pyspark.sql import Row
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2021.3.1\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\me\anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\pyspark\__init__.py", line 51, in <module>
    from pyspark.context import SparkContext
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2021.3.1\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\me\anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\pyspark\context.py", line 33, in <module>
    from pyspark.broadcast import Broadcast, BroadcastPickleRegistry
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2021.3.1\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\me\anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\pyspark\broadcast.py", line 25, in <module>
    from pyspark.cloudpickle import print_exec

ImportError: cannot import name 'print_exec' from 'pyspark.cloudpickle' (C:\Users\me\anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\pyspark\cloudpickle\__init__.py)
```

#### Specs

I am working in PyCharm IDE (PyCharm Community Edition 2021.3.1)

Python 3.10.4 | packaged by conda-forge | (main, Mar 30 2022, 08:38:02) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]

`>conda list | grep pyspark`

pyspark 3.2.1

`>conda info`

conda version : 4.12.0

conda-build version : 3.20.5

python version : 3.8.5.final.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the files were not there, I just downloaded pyspark manually from the website and replaced the previos pyspark installation with the newly downloaded one.

This got rid of all the import errors.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if you have python lib in your path